# Assert that an event was observed

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, qunit, backbone-events

How can I assert, in a QUnit test case, that a specific Backbone event was observed?

The application uses [Backbone.js events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) (Backbone.js version 1.3.3) for communicating between components. A simple view responds to a button click, by triggering a custom event on the event bus:

```javascript
// foo.js

const WheelView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #btn-spin-wheel": "onSpinButtonClick",
    },

    onSpinButtonClick: function () {
        console.log("DEBUG: clicked #btn-spin-wheel");
        Backbone.trigger("wheel:spin");
    },
});
```

I want a [QUnit](https://qunitjs.com) test case (QUnit version 1.22.0) that asserts “when this button is selected, event "foo" appears on the event bus”.

The test case will also need to know other aspects of the event (such as optional arguments), so I need a function *defined in the test case* that the test case arranges as a callback for the specific event.

This is the latest test case I've tried, by making a Sinon (version 1.9.0) spy function for the event callback:

```javascript
// test-foo.js

QUnit.module("Button “btn-spin-wheel”", {
    beforeEach: function (assert) {
        this.wheelView = new WheelView();
    },
    afterEach: function (assert) {
        delete this.wheelView;
    },
});

QUnit.test(
    "Should observe the “wheel:spin” event.",
    function (assert) {
        assert.expect(1);

        const spinWheelButton = document.querySelector(
            "#qunit-fixture #btn-spin-wheel");
        const eventListener = sinon.spy(function () {
            console.log("DEBUG:QUnit: received ‘wheel:spin’ event");
        });
        Backbone.once("wheel:spin", eventListener);

        const done = assert.async();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            spinWheelButton.click();
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                assert.ok(eventListener.calledOnce);
            }.bind(this));
            done();
        }.bind(this), 500);
    });
```

The `console.log` invocations are to help me understand which functions are being called and which are not. I expect to see both:

```
DEBUG: clicked #btn-spin-wheel
DEBUG:QUnit: received ‘wheel:spin’ event
```

Instead, only the click message appears:

```
DEBUG: clicked #btn-spin-wheel
```

This is confirmed because the test case fails:

```
Button “btn-spin-wheel”: Should observe the “wheel:spin” event. (3, 0, 3)    579 ms
    1.  Assertion after the final `assert.async` was resolved    @ 578 ms
        Source: Assert.prototype.ok@file:///usr/share/javascript/qunit/qunit.js:1481:3

    2.  failed, expected argument to be truthy, was: false    @ 578 ms
        Expected: true
        Result: false
        Source: @file://[…]/test-foo.html:50:29

    3.  Expected 1 assertions, but 2 were run    @ 579 ms
        Source: @file://[…]/test-foo.html:36:13

Source: @file://[…]/test-foo.html:36:13
```

I have read about [QUnit support for asynchronous testing](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/async) and I am experimenting with different `assert.async` and `setTimeout` usages, as suggested in the documentation examples. So far it is to no avail.

How should I use QUnit, Sinon, and Backbone, to assert (the existence, and specific properties of) a specific observed event from the app?

Comment: Hmm, well, your inner `setTimeout` has no actually timeout... you need a second argument on there (like `50`). That said, I'm not sure that this is, in fact, asynchronous. While a "real" click (and handler) is async, in this case you're manually triggering the event, so maybe it's not async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be an interaction *between* test cases. The test cases manipulate the listeners and fire events onto the event hub; but all the test cases share the *same* event hub.

So when the test cases run asynchronously, instead of the test cases being isolated, events fired in one can affect another.

The workaround I have implemented is a custom event queue for each test case, that is managed in the `QUnit.module.beforeEach` and `….afterEach`:

```javascript
/**
 * Set up an event hub fixture during `testCase`.
 *
 * @param testCase: The QUnit test case during which the fixture
 * should be active.
 * @param eventHub: The Backbone.Events object on which the fixture
 * should exist.
 */
setUpEventsFixture: function (testCase, eventHub) {
    testCase.eventHubPrevious = eventHub._events;
    eventHub._events = [];
},

/**
 * Tear down an event hub fixture for `testCase`.
 *
 * @param testCase: The QUnit test case during which the fixture
 * should be active.
 * @param eventHub: The Backbone.Events object on which the fixture
 * should exist.
 */
tearDownEventsFixture: function (testCase, eventHub) {
    eventHub._events = testCase.eventHubPrevious;
},
```

By using these in the test module definitions:

```javascript
QUnit.module("Button “btn-spin-wheel”", {
    beforeEach: function (assert) {
        setUpEventsFixture(this, Backbone);
        this.wheelView = new WheelView();
    },
    afterEach: function (assert) {
        delete this.wheelView;
        tearDownEventsFixture(this, Backbone);
    },
});
```

The test cases now can continue to use code that uses the common `Backbone` object as the event hub, but their events are isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to register a listener for your event and use `assert.async` to listen for it, something like this:

```
var done = assert.async();
Backbone.once("wheel:spin", function(event) {
    done();
});

const spinWheelButton = document.querySelector("#qunit-fixture #btn-spin-wheel");
spinWheelButton.click();
```

It may just be that your code is not behaving as you expect because of the `setTimeout` calls.

[Here](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/async) you can find further documentation for QUnit's `async`.

Comment: I need the test case to assert “this specific function (the registered callback) was called”, so that I can find out how it was called. I don't see how your example does that.

Comment: Why do you need to assert that a callback defined in your test is executed? I don't see what exactly you are wanting to test here

Comment: Have you tried that code? Calling `done` that early causes the test case to end before any other code is run, meaning I don't get to make any assertions after that.